# How does one find prices from Amazon's site programmatically?

Tags: amazon-marketplace

So Amazon has lots of different APIs for different things, and it's hard to find the one I'm looking for.

I have a client that sells things and checks Amazon's lowest price to know where to price their things (slightly under the lowest thing there). They want functionality integrated into their inventory system that would automatically find the product's lowest price on Amazon and display that. I was wondering which AWS service is best suited to this task.

I see the Product Advertising API, and that looks like the closest thing right now. Is that so?

I don't really want to rely on a scraper when Amazon provides a programmatic interface to this information somewhere, which I know they do because many other products have this. Some say that they can just download a dump of Amazon's products and use that locally -- I'm open to that option too if anyone can point me in its direction.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, the technically appropriate API is the Product Advertising API, using the ItemLookup/ItemSearch operations or the Seller* operations.

https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html

I would also advise you to check the licensing agreement for this API, notably clause 4 (i).

Comment: clause 4... thanks for doing the leg work for me here - really important to know that section

Comment: To speed up the search, here are the docs for  [ItemLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) and [ItemPrice](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemSearch.html).

Comment: Where is the link to the licensing agreement of note?

Comment: FYI, you must "Have completed 3 qualifying sales in 180 days" to be able to request API keys.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Amazon Marketplace Web Service ([api](https://developer.amazonservices.com/), [description](http://bookscouter.com/blog/2012/02/amazons-new-pricing-information-through-the-mws-products-api/))

This service can group all of the available offers into ‘buckets’ and shows the lowest price from each bucket bucket.

Each bucket has a unique combination of:

- Sub-Condition (New, Like New, Very Good, Good, Acceptable)
- FulfillmentChannel (FBA or Merchant-Fulfilled)
- ShipsDomestically (True, False, Unknown)
- ShippingTime (0-2 days, 3-7 days, 8-13 days, 14 or more days)
- SellerPositiveFeedbackRating (98-100%, 95-97%, 90-94%, 80-89%,
  70-79%, Less than 70%, Just launched)

  [image: sample results]

Someone made a really cool demo of the API [here](http://www.roundsphere.com/visualize-mws-products/)

Answer (score 3):

We cannot get the entire amazon products using API.They had made certain restrictions to the usage of API such that it would be more relevant to advertising use case only.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote that small `python` module to achieve such a task: https://github.com/iMilnb/awstools/blob/master/mods/awsprice.py

Basically, it fetches the prices from Amazon's website and convert them to a nice and parsable `python dict`.

I wrote two example functions that show how to use the resulting `dict` to dump an instance price on various terms along with a `CSV` converter.

Answer (score -2):

There is a [reply to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106403/535203) which lists all the `.js` files containing the prices, which are barely JSON files (with only a `callback(...);` statement to remove).

Here is an exemple for Linux On Demand prices : http://aws-assets-pricing-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/pricing/ec2/linux-od.js

(Get the full list [directly on that reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106403/535203))