# AWS programmatic billing access with Ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, billing

On Amazon's [Programmatic Billing Access](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html) page is a link to Sample Code and Libraries which links to the [Ruby SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/). However, I see no mention of accessing billing information via the Ruby SDK. Is it currently possible? If not, is there some example using any of the AWS SDKs for getting billing information?

**Edit:** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334035/get-ec2-pricing-programmatically) looks similar. I found [this Ruby gem](https://github.com/CloudHealth/amazon-pricing) but it looks like [you do the calculation yourself](http://www.hightechinthehub.com/2012/03/programmatically-retrieving-aws-pricing/) so it's still an estimate. I want the exact costs for my particular servers so I don't have to keep track of what factors affect Amazon's pricing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like programmatic billing just puts a file in an S3 bucket that you specify. I'm waiting for the first file in the right format to appear with some billing data, but I've written the following using the Fog gem:

```
# Returns contents of the billing data file for the given year and month.
#
# Example:
#   csv_str = read_billing_file 2011, 1
#   csv_str = read_billing_file 2013, 12
#
def read_billing_file year, month
  connection = Fog::Storage.new(provider: 'AWS') # credentials in fog.yml
  month = "0#{month}" if month.to_s.size == 1
  regex = /aws-cost-allocation-#{year}-#{month}\.csv$/
  cost_file = connection.directories.get(S3_BUCKET).files.detect {|file|
    file.key =~ regex
  }
  return nil unless cost_file
  cost_file.body
end
```