# How to get dynamic cost of an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, ec2-api-tools

I am working to get the cost of an EC2 instance attached with EBS volumes of different sizes,

For this, I am currently getting the values from AWS calculator, but every time the values will change, so I have to change them.

So is there any Java SDK or API's through which I can fetch the cost of an instance per hour?

I basically want values for instances like t2.micro and m4.large attached with 100gb and 500gb storage volumes?

How can I fetch directly from Amazon Web Services?

I have already tried looking for the various API's in AWS, but I have not have found anything useful.

AWS has provided one CSV and JSON file which first has too much values, and also they do not talk about storage cost attached to it.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-explorer-api.html

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7334035/get-ec2-pricing-programmatically